# How do I make the value undefined in PHP false?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with laravel with remote api. You have the option of attaching multiple emails. These e-mails have radio button and checkbox options. But they don't always have to be elected. That's why I get this error. Here are examples with code. I will be glad if you help me.

If nothing is selected in the second email I get this error.

`Undefined offset: 1`

*html*

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">E-posta</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control email-address" name="email[]" placeholder="E-Posta giriniz">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input class="primary-radio" type="radio" name="primaryEmail" value="0" checked autocomplete="off"> <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input class="ban-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="optOut[]" value="0" autocomplete="off"> <span class="fas fa-ban"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input class="invalid-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="invalid[]" value="0" autocomplete="off"> <span class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*php*

```
    // Emails
    $emails = $request->input('email');
    $primaryEmail = $request->input('primaryEmail');
    $optOut = $request->input('optOut');
    $invalid = $request->input('invalid');

    $emailAddresses = array();

    $e = 0;
    foreach ($emails as $emailKey => $emailValue) {
        $emailAddresses[$emailKey] = [
            'emailAddress' => $emailValue,
            'invalid' => (intval($invalid[$e]) == $emailKey) ? true : false,
            'lower' => $emailValue,
            'optOut' => (intval($optOut[$e]) == $emailKey) ? true : false,
            'primary' => (intval($primaryEmail) == $emailKey) ? true : false,
        ];
        $e++;
    }

    dd($emailAddresses);
```

*array output*

```
    array:2 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "emailAddress" => "test@live.com"
        "invalid" => true
        "lower" => "test@live.com"
        "optOut" => true
        "primary" => true
      ]
      1 => array:5 [▼
        "emailAddress" => "hi@test.com"
        "invalid" => true
        "lower" => "hi@test.com"
        "optOut" => true
        "primary" => false
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: you could do a checker before your foreach loop. you could do if($emails->isEmpty()){ return false }else { loop}

Comment: Use [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation) after form submition, and then check if those values are set, if they are then execute the code.

Comment: A checkbox and I think also a radio button are not send through the request when not selected. This means that its possible that your keys do not match or are not set at all.

Comment: no need for isset with laravel, just add a default value if there's no value `$optOut = $request->input('optOut', false);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case based on your HTML, when you have for example 3 emails:

Email 1 < Has all boxes selected

Email 2 < Has only the checkbox optOut checked

Email 3 < Has only the 2 checkboxes checked

Your result will look something like this:

```
[
    'email' => [
        0 => 'Email1',
        1 => 'Email2', 
        2 => 'Email3'
    ],
    'primaryEmail' => 0,
    'optOut' => [
        0 => 0,
        1 => 0,
        2 => 0
    ],
    'invalid' => [
        0 => 0,
        1 => 0
    ]

]
```

The biggest problem you are facing at the moment is that your keys could never match up with different combinations.

One way to fix this is to already use a key in your HTML:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">E-posta</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control email-address" name="email[<SOME KEY HERE>]" placeholder="E-Posta giriniz">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input class="primary-radio" type="radio" name="primaryEmail" value="0" checked autocomplete="off"> <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input class="ban-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="optOut[<SOME KEY HERE>]" value="0" autocomplete="off"> <span class="fas fa-ban"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input class="invalid-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="invalid[<SOME KEY HERE>]" value="0" autocomplete="off"> <span class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Where SOME KEY HERE must be the same for all fields (Even the primaryEmail field if you want to keep track to what email the primary field belongs).

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for. Thank you.